# What's :locals for in render in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

Here is the API definition for render:

```
render(options = {}, locals = {}, &block)

Returns the result of a render that’s dictated by the options hash. The primary options are:

    :partial - See ActionView::Partials.

    :file - Renders an explicit template file (this used to be the old default), add :locals to pass in those.

    :inline - Renders an inline template similar to how it’s done in the controller.

    :text - Renders the text passed in out.
```

There is no explanation about what's the purpose of locals here? What's locals for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

1. `<%= render :partial => "account" %>`

   This means there is already an instance variable called `@account` for the partial and you pass it to the partial.
2. `<%= render :partial => "account", :locals => { :account => @buyer } %>`

   This means you pass a local instance variable called `@buyer` to the `account` partial and the variable in the `account` partial is called `@account`. I.e., the hash `{ :account => @buyer }` for `:locals` is just used for passing the local variable to the partial. You can also use the keyword `as` in the same way:

   `<%= render :partial => "contract", :as => :agreement`

   which is the same as:

   `<%= render :partial => "contract", :locals => { :agreement => @contract }`

Answer (score 9):

To pass local variables to the partial template, as opposed to controller instance variables.

See [Section 3.4.4, Passing Local Variables in the Layouts and Rendering Guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)